# Help understanding factor modeling, solving for residuals

Tags: factor-models, models, factor-loading

I am trying to understand and implement a factor model, and I think I might be having some issues.  I am trying to solve for the residuals in the equation:

$$
R_{i} = \sum_{A=1}^{K}\beta_{iA} f_{A} + \epsilon_{i}
$$

where R is an N x 1 (i = 1, ..., N)  matrix, and there are K latent factors.  I know the values inside the B (factor loadings) matrix and R (returns) matrices beforehand.

My understanding is that this equation gives the values the residuals matrix:

$$
\epsilon = (I_{N} - H)R
$$
$$
H = \beta(\beta'\beta)^{-1}\beta'
$$

Is this correct way to solve for the residuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see $(Y,X)$, you want a relation ship between $X$ and $Y$.

You will assume Linear regression

I.e you assume it exists $\beta$ such that $Y=X\beta + \epsilon$ and you want to find $\beta$.

Solution: $\hat{\beta}=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$ and $\epsilon = Y-\hat{Y}=Y-X\hat{\beta}=(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')Y$

So if you apply to your case :

$X\to B$

$\beta \to f$

$Y\to R$

$\epsilon \to \epsilon$

Comment: So my equation is correct, right?  I think it is the same as your answer